# Wordpress dynamic content

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently have around 100 rows in a table on my website, which include a URL and few sets of numbers pulled from a database on my server. What I would like to do is to dynamically create pages based on a cell of each row, which would contain data pulled from the same database. For example, each row (displayed in the table) would look like this:

`Icon (url) | Name (url) | Number 1 | Number 2 | Number 3 | Number 4 | Number 5`

Inside my database however, each row is like this:

`Icon (url) | Name (url) | Number 1 | Number 2 | Number 3 | Number 4 | Number 5 | Description (large body of text) | LargeImage (url)`

Since I have so many entries, I would like to be able to have some way to generate the pages based on the name of the row in the database (it would take too long to make each page individually, and I will be updating this table frequently with content), so I can display more of the information out of the database row (the description, largeimage etc) that I wouldn't be able to fit into the table.

Are there any plugins for Wordpress that can do this, and if not, how would I go about doing this in PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how to best integrate this into WP, but it's fairly straightforward in PHP. You just have a file like mypage.php?id={#} where the # is the individual record's ID. You pull the ID using GET (`$id = $_GET["id"];`) and then run an SQL query with it as the WHERE, take the results and populate the page with that row of data. Then, using .htaccess, you can do what WP does and make this look like a URL (ie. mypage/2/).

You can create the custom page by using a [method like this](http://www.balkhis.com/web-designs-resources/custom-page-for-wordpress/) for example.

You *could* integrate this into WP by creating a separate file (other than single.php, for example) that would run this PHP script, but include the WP header and footer to make it fit into the theme. However, this wouldn't really be fully integrated into single.php and therefore wouldn't appear in the posts section in the admin or anything. Is that a requirement?

Comment: No, I'm only interested in preserving the header and footer of my Wordpress theme, the actual pages generated don't need to show up in any post feeds or RSS or anything. Do you happen to know a website with a detailed example of how to do the steps you described?

Comment: I just posted a link for how to create a separate page above, if that's the road you're looking at taking. Otherwise, you can just create this script in the root directory of your WP installation and run it like a standalone script. As for the PHP, if you Google "displaying MYSQL data using PHP" you'll get an idea of how to create the custom page (there's lots of tutorials). Just remember, in the SQL query, you'll use that GET command above to populate the WHERE id = $id to pull the necessary query.

Comment: I was mainly talking about an example for the PHP gets, but thanks!